# Spring Security OAUTH2: configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer) not executed

Tags: spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

I have a Spring application deployed in a Tomcat container.

Unfortunately we have a weird combination of XML and Java based spring security configuration, which complicates the problem...

I am trying to enable the OAUTH2 authorization server in the application, using @EnableAuthorizationServer and extending AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter. The problem is that the configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer security) method is not executed, and obviously some very important things, like the password encoder is not initialized.

I am assuming that this is because we also have security configuration in an XML file, but no matter how long I try to figure it out, I cannot find the solution.

Our setup is: the HTTP security and the definition of the authenticationManager are in the XML file and the definition of the OAUTH authorization server is Java based.

Any ideas would be more than welcome...

Edit 1:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class AuthorizationServerConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

@Autowired
private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

@Override
public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer security) throws Exception {
    security.passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
}

@Override
public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clientsConfigurer) throws Exception {
    clientsConfigurer.inMemory()
            .withClient("client")
            .secret("secret")
            .authorizedGrantTypes("password")
            .authorities("ROLE_USER")
            .scopes("read");
}

@Override
public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
    endpoints
            .authenticationManager(authenticationManager)
            .tokenEnhancer(accessTokenConverter())
            .tokenStore(tokenStore());
}

@Bean
public TokenStore tokenStore() {
    return new JwtTokenStore(accessTokenConverter());
}

@Bean
public DefaultTokenServices tokenServices(ClientDetailsService clientDetailsService) {
    DefaultTokenServices tokenServices = new DefaultTokenServices();
    tokenServices.setClientDetailsService(clientDetailsService);
    tokenServices.setTokenEnhancer(accessTokenConverter());
    tokenServices.setTokenStore(tokenStore());
    tokenServices.setAccessTokenValiditySeconds(accessTokenValidity);
    return tokenServices;
}

@Bean
public JwtAccessTokenConverter accessTokenConverter() {
    JwtAccessTokenConverter converter = new JwtAccessTokenConverter();
    return converter;
}
}
```

Then, this is the xml config

```
    <http pattern="/oauth/*" create-session="stateless">
        <csrf disabled="true"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/oauth/token" access="isFullyAuthenticated()"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/oauth/token_key" access="permitAll()"/>
        <http-basic/>
    </http>

   <authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <authentication-provider user-service-ref="userDetailsService">
            <password-encoder ref="passwordEncoder"/>
        </authentication-provider>

        <authentication-provider>
            <user-service>
                <user name="client" password="secret" authorities="ROLE_USER"/>
            </user-service>
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>
```

I also have the problem that if I do not add the second authentication provider in the above authentication manager, the OAUTH2 /token end point will fail and tell me that it does not find the mentioned client.... I have no idea why it needs the authentication provider there, I always thought that this is covered by the definition of the clients in the authorization server.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@ComponentScan("com.authentication")
@ImportResource("classpath:spring-security.xml")
public class SecurityConfig {
}
```

Comment: Would be easier to help if you posted relevant pieces of code/configuration. Thanks.

Comment: Hope it helps, I added code that I found relevant...